# Handling missing fields in documents using EF Core and MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to query a MongoDB collection using EF Core. When a primitive-type field is missing (i.e. **Password**), it's returned as `null` (as expected), but when a complex type field is missing (the **Group** field in this case) in ANY document within the collection, I get the below error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MongoStore.MongoContext'.
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Element 'Group' not found.
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.get_Item(String name)
   at lambda_method8(Closure, QueryContext, BsonDocument)
   at MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryingEnumerable`2.Enumerator.MoveNextHelper()
   at MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryingEnumerable`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Here's how I'm trying to query the database:

```
app.MapGet(
        "/users",
        (MongoContext context) =>
        {
            var users = context.Users.FirstOrDefault();
            return users;
        }
    );
```

Model class:

```cs
[Collection("Users")]
public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Group? Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Context class:

```cs
public class MongoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; init; }

    public MongoContext(DbContextOptions<MongoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you try applied `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` attribute to `Group` property?

Comment: @YongShun yes, I did. But I still get the same error.